# Туплю жоска - картинка CSS и DIV

Tags: css, html, img

Есть картинка, она размещена в блоке DIV, в этом же блоке есть ещё один DIV с цветом и прозрачностью (хочу сделать наложение цвета на картинку). В итоге вижу только картинку[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
<div class="box-img">
    <img src="img/img1.jpg" alt="">
    <div class="overcolor">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Какие размеры заданы для блока .overcolor?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Вариант с [псевдоэлементом](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-elements) after

```css
.box-img {
  position: relative;
  width: 250px;
  height: 400px;
}

.box-img-src {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.box-img:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  top: 0;
  background: rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
  transition: background .4s ease;
}

.box-img:hover:after {
  background: rgba(255,255,255,0);
}
```

```html
<div class="box-img">
  <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1558369178-6556d97855d0?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=634&q=80" class="box-img-src">
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

```css
.img {
    width: 200px;
    height: 150px;
    background: url(https://www.imgonline.com.ua/examples/bee-on-daisy-blurred.jpg) no-repeat center top;
}

.overlay {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #000;
    opacity: 0.8;
}

.img:hover .overlay {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="img">
    <div class="overlay"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Если задача стоит использовать именно ту разметку, что у вас есть то можно использовать такой вариант:

```
<div class="box-img">
    <img src="img/img1.jpg" alt="">
    <div class="overcolor">
    </div>
</div>


.box-img {
  position: relative;
}

.box-img img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}

.overcolor {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  /* тут указываем цвет затенения и коэф. прозрачности*/
  background-color: #000;
  opacity: .7;
}
```

В этом случае размер блока будет определяться размерами вложенной картинки без необходимости жесткой фиксации его высоты.